# Check current subclass in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an Activity called `RootActivity`, which will be extended to **all** of Activities in my apps (or in the other word, it will be the super class and all of my Activities will be its sub class).

Now, lets say I have 3 Activities in my apps : `MainActivity`, `DetailActivity` and `AboutActivity`, and all of them extends `RootActivity`. How can I check where is the current active Activity, **in the `RootActivity` code?**

The simple example is, lets say I want to `Toast` "This is MainActivity" when I was in MainActivity.

I think I can use `if (this instanceof RootActivity)` if I put this code in the sub classes (the three Activities above). But, **what I'm looking for is how to code it in RootActivity.**

Thanks for your time

Comment: Why would you do that instead of using polymorpism? Create a method which sub types can override.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.. There has to be a better way of achieving what you want..

Comment: You can use `this.getClass().getSimpleName()` or you can use `this instanceof MainActivity` or you can override a method, as suggested above.

Comment: How can i detect the subclass using abstract method?Can you give me a little example?Thanks

Comment: @DavidConrad can i use this instanceof MainActivity in the RootActivity? I think i should put it on the sub class (MainACtivity)

Comment: Of course you can use `this instanceof MainActivity` in RootActivity. If the actual runtime type of the object is MainActivity, it will return true, even if the code is located in a method that was inherited from RootActivity.

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes, its working in RootActivity. Thanks for your help! Please answer my question so i can accept your answer, Thanks for your help

Comment: I finally did write up my comments as an answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This will give the class name for the current object whichever type it is.

```
public class RootActivity {

  public String getThisClassName() {
    return this.getClass().getName();
  }
}
```

See demonstration here: http://ideone.com/5IGRW0

Comment: Sorry, do you mean this.getClass().getName();? I will try this, Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the guy in the comment give me (i think) a better solution. Its too bad i can only give one upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this instanceof MainActivity` in your `RootActivity`. It might seem at first glance that this wouldn't work, since it is in code residing in `RootActivity`, but if your `MainActivity` class is descended from `RootActivity`, then it will inherit the code and if the actual run-time type of the object is `MainActivity`, it will return true.

So, one way to write it would be:

```
public class RootActivity extends Activity {
    // ...

    public String getToastMessage() {
        if (this instanceof MainActivity) {
            return "This is MainActivity";
        }
        if (this instanceof DetailActivity) {
            return "This is DetailActivity";
        }
        if (this instanceof AboutActivity) {
            return "This is AboutActivity";
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

However, code that explicitly tests the class of objects like this is generally considered less elegant than polymorphic code. You could also have a method in the base class which is overridden in each subclass:

```
public class RootActivity extends Activity {
    // ...

    public String getToastMessage() {
        return "I don't know where I am!";
    }

    // ...
}

public class MainActivity extends RootActivity {
    // ...

    @Override
    public String getToastMessage() {
        return "This is MainActivity";
    }

    // ...
}
```

And so on for the other classes.

Either approach will work if you want to have behavior vary between the classes. If, on the other hand, you only want to do what is directly asked in your question, which is to have a toast display the name of the class, then a simpler solution is possible since objects in Java know what class they belong to (what is sometimes called Run-Time Type Identification, or RTTI), including the name of their class:

```
public class RootActivity extends Activity {
    // ...

    public String getToastMessage() {
        return "This is " + this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    // ...
}
```